# Tish'a Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

*Prime factorization: 3 X 83*

Comment: you've started 250, and haven't accepted one here.

Comment: @msh210 Oh. Thanks. It was an oversight. I'm surprised that 250 doesn't have more answers yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yosef was born 249 years before the Exodus.

(He was 39 when Yaakov and his family arrived there, and the Egyptian exile lasted 210 years.)

Answer (score 1):

[Reportedly](http://townwebsite.kslrfamily.com/ZawiercieGhettoCaseStudy.htm), the last transport from [Zawiercie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zawiercie) (October 17, 1943) included 249 Jewish men who were registered into [Birkenau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz-Birkenau#Auschwitz_II-Birkenau).

Answer (score 1):

כלב בן יפנה = 249..............